# Count of products NOT sold...per store, per day over the past month

Tags: t-sql, data-warehouse

I'm struggling with an interview question I had recently.  3 dimension tables (Product, Store and Date) and 1 fact table (Sales).  The question asked for a T-SQL solution that will return the count of products **not** sold, per store, per day over the past month.

That ship has sailed...opportunity has passed, but I've since spent significant time trying to back into a solution, to no avail, and would like to close the loop.  Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically "what didn't happen" is answered using a coverage table. This may have been a "trick" question to see if you knew about using a Factless Fact table do to negative analysis.

This table would be one row / day / product / store, identifying all the products that were available in a particular store on a particular day. You'd then use that table and do a set subtraction of the products that sold from the sales fact, to get the products that didn't sell.

It doesn't make sense necessarily to join to product dim because not all products may be sold in all stores. It was likely just a question to see if you could build the necessary SQL, but I think it's a poor question in general.

Comment: Yes, realistically you would expect at least a store-products table, with valid date intervals, to construct that part of the query.

Comment: Thank you both for your feedback.  That is where I hit the wall.  I was quickly able to get to the point where I had identified products not sold, created zero rows for them and then had a count for the period as a whole, but then doing the same at a store and date level was the reason for my post.  I thought it may have been a trick...but wasn't sure enough to respond that way.  Live and learn.

Comment: @paul, I don't think it was a trick. The question can answered as posed, without a coverage table, it is just that typically you would expect to see a coverage table to help reduce noise in the results. In lieu of a coverage table, you construct one on the fly using cross joins and restricting the range of days. With either approach, you still need to anti-join what did sell.

Comment: @PeterRadocchia - Yep. I expect that the question was just to test the ability of prospective developers to use ideas like cross joins (often considered an "error") in a way that makes sense and is useful.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

1. cross join product, store and date, then filter for the past month
2. anti join (1) to the fact table, project what remains, and aggregate by store and date.

any more help and it might be unfair to others.

Comment: Thank you...I'll give it a try.  Just to reiterate, the window for a valid response on my end is most definitely closed.  Not looking to circumvent or misrepresent any response as my own.

Answer (score 0):

Included dates in the queries

--Tables

```
CREATE TABLE dimProduct(ProductID INT,ProductName VARCHAR(50))

CREATE TABLE dimStore(StoreID INT,StoreName VARCHAR(50))

CREATE TABLE dimDate(DateID INT,dimDate VARCHAR(50))

CREATE TABLE factSales(ProductID INT,StoreID INT,DateID INT)
```

--=Final Query

```
SELECT StoreID,DateID,count(ProductID) AS CountOfProductsNotSold
FROM
(
SELECT StoreID,DateID,ProductID FROM dimProduct CROSS JOIN dimStore CROSS JOIN dimDate WHERE dimDate >= '01/01/2013'
EXCEPT
SELECT StoreID,d.DateID,ProductID FROM factSales s JOIN dimDate d ON s.DateID = d.DateID WHERE dimDate >= '01/01/2013'
)T
GROUP BY StoreID,DateID
```